# Doctrine Query Error for JOIN: Expected end of string, got 'I'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My PHP Code is:

```
        $company = $qb->select("c")
                  ->from("CRMBundle:TblCompanyDomain","cd")
                  ->join("cd.company","c")
                  ->leftJoin("CRMBundle:TblCompanyAddress",
                             "ca",
                             "WITH",
                             "ca.company = c")
                  ->join("ca.country","cc")
                  ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                      $qb->expr()->in("cd.domain",":domain"),
                      $qb->expr()->eq("c.channel",":channel_id")
                  ))
                  ->setParameters($parameters)
                  ->setMaxResults(1)
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

End Received DQL code is:

```
SELECT 
    c 
FROM 
     CRMBundle:TblCompanyDomain cd 
     INNER JOIN cd.company c 
     LEFT JOIN CRMBundle:TblCompanyAddress ca WITH ca.company = c 
     INNER JOIN ca.country cc 
WHERE 
     cd.domain IN(:domain) AND 
     c.channel = :channel_id
```

When I execute this query, I've received this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 44: Error: Expected end of string, got 'I' 
enter code here
```

I could not see any syntax error. Where is the problem?

My Symfony version: 2.6.11

My Doctrine Version: 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed from annotation to yml my doctrine orm mapping and fixed problems.

I've experienced to many times same problem and understand real problem. When I using Doctrine annotation with utf-8, this problem fired. May be, cause is utf-8 on Turkish. Because lower "ı" charachter's capital is "I" and lower "i" carachter's capital is "İ".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c 
FROM 
     CRMBundle:TblCompanyDomain cd 
     INNER JOIN cd.company c 
     LEFT JOIN CRMBundle:TblCompanyAddress ca WITH ca.company = c
     INNER JOIN ca.country cc 
WHERE 
     cd.domain IN(:domain) AND 
     c.channel = :channel_id
```

I think that you need c.something

Comment: Thanks for quick answer
New DQL is 
SELECT c FROM CRMBundle:TblCompanyDomain cd INNER JOIN cd.company c LEFT JOIN CRMBundle:TblCompanyAddress ca WITH ca.company = c.companyId INNER JOIN ca.country cc WHERE cd.domain IN(:domain) AND c.channel = :channel_id

But I still get the same error

Comment: When this kind of thing happens the best is going removing each part of the query and find the failure. :-)